# An SCSS function to give order to elements

Tags: css, variables, sass

I'm trying to make an image gallery and want to give order to elements in a class, and after that I want to use that variable to create a full view next to it.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="im">lorem</div>
  <div class="im">lorem</div>
</div>
```

I need every child in row to have an order and I want to get it if I need. Is that possible or do I have to code it for each element myself?
in the css is this possible?
`.row {
  &:nth-child($i)
  order: $i
}`

Comment: or can this be made with $ closest?

Comment: Show what you have tried to make it easier for those that want to help.

Comment: You mention an image gallery, but there are not even any images in your markup.

Comment: It would be better doing it with jquery or javascript i guess

Comment: You can either create mixin of different order classes and then apply them to HTML. or the best in your case i would suggest go by JS way.

Comment: can u give a simple example? how it can be done with js?